how to create a git branch base on IDEA dependency analyze result
description:

I have a large SpringApplication JAVA project about 5000 classes, I need add a new feature (1 new class or 1 new method) in it.
I want to run a swagger interface test or SpringBootTest only test what I add to the project, but IDEA will build and run whole project code, so it waste a lot of time, about 10 minutes each time.

what I have tried:

Extract only my code and dependency in production class, then create a feature branch with infrastructure, such as swagger config and SpringApplication class to develop it. It is much more faster than run whole project code, about 40s each time. But I need manually to get all dependency class one by one, which is exhausted.

question:

Any better way to create a git branch base on IDEA dependency analyze result?
Any way to run only my code rather than run whole project to test it?


10 minutes sounds like a lot of time to compile. Does that include time running tests? IntelliJ IDEA typically only builds code that changed, so I'm not sure I've understood your problem correctly. Are you generating code every time? If it is taking so long to compile, you may want to look at breaking the code base up into modules so that you can use them as libraries and they don't need to be rebuilt every time. If it's 10 minutes starting the application context for the test, you could look at fine-tuning the context for your test using @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest.classes.

Remove execution of unit test, java docs generation, code style check, git integration check, enabled build cache and other unwated task before running project for testing purpose, or can you show maven or gradel file hiding critical details to give more inputs?

@silentsudo I have already removed all unit test, java docs generation, code style check, git integration check. And I have already enabled build cache, but when I switch branch, it will build whole project. My project got several module and maven file, so it is hard to provide it, sry.

which is your build environment gradle/maven?

Have you tried running the application by skipping the test cases? There is a command in maven/ gradle depends what you are using to build the application by skipping test cases, may be that will be helpful?

sry I didn't run any test cases, thx for answering.
